# 3rd Party API is rejecting HttpClient Get Request because of CORS - works in browser and powershell

Tags: angular

Just as the title states. I'm getting a lot of problems with CORS and using a 3rd party API on a simple GET request.

In my browser and powershell I can hit the API directly with the same URL and get the JSON data just fine. When I wrap it into an Angular request with HttpClient, I get the CORS error.

I can't modify the server and haven't found any suitable answers for my use case.

I tried to modify my headers to match what my browser sends after inspecting the network traffic:

```
return this._http.get<FullResponse>(finalEndpoint,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Host': 'api.<third party>.com',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
          'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
          'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive'
        })
      });
```

But I get the errors:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Host"
Refused to set unsafe header "Accept-Encoding"
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection"
```

As well as still getting a CORS error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<GET URL>' from origin 'Localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What are my options?

Comment: The api requires a “host” header of itself?

Comment: That's what it has when I look at the traffic in Chrome, so I'm assuming there's some interception going on.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, let the browser set that header. When making an Ajax/fetch call from a web app to an api of different origin, CORS headers must be emitted from the server. This api may require you to register your web app’s origin for this to happen.

Comment: This is also why it works from PS and direct browser entry and not the Angular app. Ajax/fetch are more restrictive and enforces CORS... for your protection :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to set the Host, Accept-Encoding, and Connection headers. They are only able to be set by the User Agent for security reasons. See the list of [forbidden header names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name). You should try to figure out the original CORS error that you get when sending the request with the HttpClient.

UPDATE:

Since you can't contact the third party to change the configuration another option is to use a different server to proxy the API requests. If you already have a server at xyz.com then you can create an endpoint like xyz.com/3rdPartyAPI and send your requests there. On the server you can then request the content the usual way with curl or wget or anything else and then forward the response back to the client.

Comment: "You should try to figure out the original CORS error that you get when sending the request with the HttpClient." - Ok... So any help?

Comment: You need to include the error message in your question

Comment: Added it, nothing very descriptive in it.

Comment: Are you sure the 3rd party server has CORS set up properly because according to the error message it is missing the required header on the server. You can access the url in the browser because that is not a cross origin request.

Comment: I have no access to the 3rd party nor can I request them to change their configurations.

Comment: What @devin said.  One other possibly ..“localhost:4200” isn’t allowed. But, it kind of sounds like this api wasn’t built for Ajax consumption.